# PHP Call Superclass Factory Method from Subclass Factory Method

Tags: php, subclass, factory-pattern, superclass

I am writing a php app with subclasses and since I want to have multiple ways to create an object I am doing different factory methods instead of multiple constructors.

I have a `User` with factory methods

```
User::from_id
User::from_netid
```

I have several subclasses of `User`. I was previously calling the parent superconstructor, but when I switched to the factory method that constructor didn't exist.

I have `Student`, a subclass of `User`. To get it to work, I had to duplicate almost all of my superclass factory code in `User::from_id` to `load_by_id`, since in this situation the instance already existed:

```
// In Student.php - Student extends User
public static function from_id_and_course($id, $course){
    $instance = new self();
    $instance->load_by_id($id);
    $instance->course = $course;
    ...
}
```

I want to call the superclass factory method from the subclass as a starting point, and then continue to add the other fields. Something like this...

```
$instance = User::from_id($id);
```

or

```
$instance = Student::from_id($id);
```

but in these cases it gives me a `User` object, and I need a `Student` object. The only way I could accomplish this is by doing `$instance = new self()`.

How can I call the superclass factory method from the subclass as a starting point to create a new subclass factory method?

Comment: Have you tried using `parent::from_id($id);`

Comment: Just FYI you are not implementing a true factory pattern here. You are meant to have another class that acts as the factory so that any class that wants to use the student / users / whatever subclasses is loosely coupled to those not tightly coupled by calling specific methods of the user classes.

Comment: @ZeSimon - this seems to be the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern rather than the full Factory pattern

Comment: Agreed, however I think in this case he would benefit from the full factory pattern.

Comment: @HorusKol: I think you're confusing the Builder pattern (what you call the full Factory pattern) and the Factory pattern. [This is an example of the factory pattern.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4719976/492901)

Comment: @netcoder - yeah, probably... brain seems to have shutdown for the holidays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
$instance = new self();
```

`self` refers to the class where the method is defined, not the caller:

- When `Student::from_id()` is called, if it doesn't exist, it falls back to `User::from_id()`.
- In `User::from_id()`, `self` refers to `User`, not `Student`.

You'd have to use [late-static bindings](http://php.net/oop5.late-static-bindings):

```
$instance = new static();
```

However, like I always do, I'd highly recommend against it. You're better off using the object scope than the static scope. It's easier to extend, to fake or mock and incidentally, to test.

There's nothing wrong with:

```
$user = new User;
$user->from_id($id);

$student = new Student;
$student->from_id($id);
```

...it's actually better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.3 or higher, you could use the [Late Static Bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) that are now available:

```
class User
{
  public static function from_id($id)
  {
    // factory
    $object = new static();

    // setup

    // return
    return $object;
  }
}

class Student extends User { }

$student = Student::from_id($id); // $student should be of class Student
```

Note - you're probably better off setting up a whole factory class for mocking/testing/sanity...