# How to build a subclass using an inherited factory method defined in the superclass in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, static-methods, factory-pattern, self

I'm new to PHP. I have three classes, say `A`, `B`, and `C`, where `B` and `C` inherit directly from `A`. My problem is, I need a static factory, say `createInstance()` that is defined **once** for class `A`, and is applicable throughout its descendants. So when someone calls `A::createInstance()`, it returns an object of type `A`, while calling `B::createInstance()` returns an instance of `B`, and `C::createInstance()` returns an instance of `C`. I put the following code inside `createInstance()` definition in class `A`:

```
public static function createInstance() {
    return new self();
}
```

but that wouldn't be the solution to my needs, since `self` always refers to class `A` regardless of what class it's called on. In other words, calling `B::createInstance()` and `C::createInstance` always return an object of type `A`. How can I create such a factory method that returns an object of the appropriate class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a `static` keyword you can use:

```
public static function createInstance() {
    return new static();
}
```

Comment: Dear Anonymous, I learned Java with Deitel's 'Java How to Program' book. It was so useful, since it taught pretty much every and each of details of Java. It scrutinizes everything (perhaps too much). Unfortunately Deitel hasn't written such a book about PHP. I really need one such book, but haven't found any. Do you know such a book that explains details of how the language works?

Comment: @HedayatMahdipour I don't anything will be better than reading [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/). You don't have to read all of it but it has the most updated information and lots of examples.

Comment: On a very similar thread the top rated answer says that this pattern should be avoided. I don't want to overindex on that user's opinion, so I'd be curious @Anonymous if you think this is a fine pattern to use... 

Here's the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583989/php-call-superclass-factory-method-from-subclass-factory-method

Comment: @gen I’ve never needed this pattern, but it might be ok when all subclasses are known. There’s usually a better way. For example, in the linked question, I don’t see why `User` needs that method too. I would use a trait instead